# Translate python code to clojure, recursion and for loop

Tags: recursion, clojure

I am calculate k out of n combination from a length n list. I found the python code is very concise, so I did a direct translation.

```
def comb(sofar, rest, n):
     if n == 0:
         print sofar
     else:
         for i in range(len(rest)):
             comb(sofar + rest[i], rest[i+1:], n-1)

comb("", "abcde", 3)
```

yield:
abc, abd, abe etc...

Is going to be translated to clojure code:

```
(defn comb [sofar v n]
  (if (= n 0)
    (print sofar)
    (for [i (range 0 (count v))] 
      (comb  (str sofar (nth v i))   ;don't it need to be recur ?
             (subvec v (inc i))
             (dec i)))))
```

nested loop/recursion is quite confusing.

Problem is how to change code to do the same function as python code?

my clojure code doesn't seem to do the same work.

Comment: So, do you have any *particular* question?

Comment: JFYI, stackoverflow is not a free online code translation tool.

Comment: @zerkms I am practicing clojure too. Burning head to get some clean code.

Comment: Do it iteratively and ask a *particular* question when you're in stuck. Posting your broken code and asking to fix it is not how you learn. Btw, in your python code `n` is redundant, you can check the `rest` length instead.

Comment: You can't translate for in python (loop construction) directly with for in clojure (sequence generator).

Comment: Your question is almost OK, CodeFarmer.  Just explain what is going wrong in the Clojure version.  That would help people who might answer, and will avoid complaints.

Comment: For recursions that aren't deep, `recur` isn't required.  However, if your code is tail-recursive, `recur` will be more efficient, and it will allow deep recursion.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, if you want a clojure solution, think in clojure terms, write functions over sequences that generate results in lazy sequences, and let the end consumer reduce those to strings if needed. In the following, I don't use print at all, just return lazy sequences, and let the repl be the printer.

Also, you're trying to translate a python `for` directly into a clojure `for` to do looping, which isn't what it's for (no pun intended). [clojure's `for`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clj/clojure.core/for/) is a sequence generator, so you're probably getting confused there.

To get a simple solution to your problem you can use [math.combinatorics](http://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/):

```
user=> (require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as m])
user=> (m/combinations "abcde" 3)
((\a \b \c) (\a \b \d) (\a \b \e) (\a \c \d) (\a \c \e) (\a \d \e) (\b \c \d) (\b \c \e) (\b \d \e) (\c \d \e))
```

You can then write a map to convert this to strings for same output as python if needed.

```
user=> (map #(apply str %1) (m/combinations "abcde" 3))
("abc" "abd" "abe" "acd" "ace" "ade" "bcd" "bce" "bde" "cde")
```

However, I suspect you're looking for more of a tutorial on doing looping.

There's [another solution to this problem here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/enumerate-k-combinations-in-clojure-p26-from-99-problems) for creating a function to return the sequence as chars, which produces the same sequence as the above example and can be wrapped in a map for string output too. That uses recursion with a cond block to control the end of the iteration.

[Here is another good article](http://randomcomputation.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/combinations-in-clojure.html) on doing same combinations with explanation on how it works with recursion by deconstructing the problem into something that is recursive in nature.

If you want more information on recur vs imperative loop, look no further than [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673874/clojure-recur-vs-imperative-loop).

And [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/tolitius/1721519) with some examples of loop/recur vs recursion for factorials so you can directly see the syntax style between the two.

In terms of getting used to writing functions that generate sequences like this, I find [The Little Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/index.php?q=books/little-schemer) is an excellent resource at explaining the thinking process. It's written in scheme, but is quite easy to understand and apply to clojure. After this, you can then look at higher order functions (map/reduce) rather than using loop.

All in all, when doing this, if you use lazy functions everywhere, your result will generally be lazy, and you want to try and use tail-recursion if you do recurse so that you don't blow the stack when using large combination, and dumping values you're not interested in.